# uinavigationcontroller - display stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently working on an app that contains a large number of `ViewControllers`. I'm using `uinavigationcontroller` to push the a `ViewController` onto the stack and pop to a previous view controller when a back button is pressed. How would i display the `viewcontrollers` on the stack on a side bar. For example, the navigation process would look like this. `ViewController1`->`ViewController2`->`ViewController3`->`ViewController4`->`ViewController5`.

The side bar would look like this when navigated to `ViewController5`.

```
ViewController1
ViewController2
ViewController3
ViewController4
ViewController5
```

The user can then select any `viewcontroller` from the side bar, (e.g. ViewController3) and navigate to that `ViewController` without altering what's displayed on the sidebar.

Comment: Are you satisfied with below answer or need to know that how to implement it.

Comment: What exactly is your question? are you asking how to implement the side nav? how to jump back to a specific viewController? I don't see an actual question here, it appears your detailing what you want your app to do and asking us to do it for you

Comment: "How would i display the viewcontrollers on the stack on a side bar?" I'm not asking for any code. I'm just asking for a little pointer on how would I go on about this. :)

Answer (score 1):

use `[navController setViewControllers:animated]` to do whatever you want

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: inNavController.viewControllers];

// Do whatever you want with the array. Change Order add/remove view controllers.
[inNavController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```